# Knockout JS `hasFocus` within template that is called twice

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a template, which is using `hasFocus` similar to example in docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>field test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 1em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@2.2.2,bootstrap@3.3.6,knockout@3.4.0"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() {

            var VM = function() {

                var model = {};

                model = {
                    one: ko.observable(false),
                    two: ko.observable(false)
                };

                this.model = model;

            };

            ko.applyBindings(new VM());

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/template" id="first-template">
        <input type="text" class='form-control' data-bind="hasFocus: model.one">
        <p>one has<span data-bind="visible: !model.one()"> not got</span> focus now</p>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' data-bind="hasFocus: model.two">
        <p>two has<span data-bind="visible: !model.two()"> not got</span> focus now</p>
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'first-template' }"></div>
                <!-- if I uncomment the next line, it stops working... -->
                <!-- <div data-bind="template: { name: 'first-template' }"></div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It all works as expected, updating the focus state on the model correctly when entering and leaving the field. However, if I apply the template a second time, the template appears to work ok with the exception of the focus state. Is this unsupported, or am I implementing wrong? How can I use template multiple times, and still use focus state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser cannot have two `<input>` elements with focus. The `hasFocus` bind will try to give both elements a focused state. You can circumvent this behavior by using `event` bindings for both `focus` and `blur` events:

```
data-bind="event: { 
  focus: function() { 
    model.one(true) 
  }, 
  blur: function() { 
    model.one(false) 
  } 
}"
```

Check out this fiddle for a working example of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/77meefmf/

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure each copy of the template has its own viewmodel. The `hasFocus` binding is meant to represent the focus status a **single** field. If you bind it to more then one field, the results will be wrong.